# Issues accessing nested JSON objects via javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the JSON i'm getting:

```
{"status":"failure","msg":{"name":["can't be blank"],"email":["can't be blank","is invalid"]}}
```

This is the javascript i'm using:

```
$("#sign_in_form").submit(function() {
  var success_function = function(data) {
    if(data.status == 'failure') {
      $("#error_msg").html(data.msg.name)
    }
  };

  $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), success_function, "json");
});
```

The error I'm getting from Firebug is:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1 :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 6182" data: no]
```

Everything works fine.  My javascript can access the `data.status` value but using `data.msg.name` produces the uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
data.msg.name[0]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I think it might be data.msg.name[0].

Comment: It is in fact data.msg.name[0].  The ones above are not correct.

Comment: @Elliot Nelson tnx for correcting me i was just testing the same thing

Comment: @EverTheLearner updated the answer, since Elliot answered it too in the comment

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
$("#error_msg").html(data.msg.name[0] || '');
```